# can an html input be put inside a text area

Tags: html, forms

For example I have limited space and I want the submit button to appear in the bottom right of the text area. Something like this?:

```
<textarea value='text message' name='messageSMS' id='messageSMS' onfocus='clearInput(this)' onblur='clearInput(this)'>
<input value='send' id='sendSMS' type='submit' name='submit' />
</textarea>
```

Comment: Seeing as you'll need to make room at the bottom of the textarea for the button anyway (assuming that you don't want stuff people type to be underneath the button and hidden), I'm not sure this will really save a significant amount of space. It'll also look weird.

Comment: It would probably confuse users more than having a scrollable textarea.

Comment: point taken. The box is only 190px x 120px so losing 30px or so and the title which is another 30 or so is not ideal. Any other ideas welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Instead, you could use CSS to move it over the textbox.

For example: (Tested in Firefox on Windows 7; [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/evufa3/edit))

```
#sendSMS{
    width: 40px;
    position: relative;
    left:-47px;
    top: -7px;
}
```

You might want to make the button cover the entire height of the textbox.

Comment: yea that is what I was thinking initially. But as Pointy mentioned I don't want people typing underneath it.

I'm just trying to find the most convinient space saving options for a small SMS sending box, any other ideas very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS positioning.